# Passing encoded email token to flask method

Tags: python, flask

I'm working to modify a [cookiecutter](https://github.com/wdm0006/cookiecutter-flask) Flask app.  I'm trying to follow https://realpython.com/blog/python/handling-email-confirmation-in-flask/ to add email authorization.

My original page captures just the email. I then want to ask interested users to fill out a larger form to complete registration.

To do this I send an email that contains the email in the token and looks like:

```
Welcome! Please follow this link to complete registration:

http://127.0.0.1:5000/register/?token=ImNsdWVtYXJpbmUxQG1haWxpbmF0b3IuY29tIg.CafSGw.5f9hjRwQDeDWmQu4--jYVgbzezw
```

I then want to capture the token and complete registration doing something like:

```
@blueprint.route("/register/<token>", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def register(token):
    form = RegisterForm(request.form, csrf_enabled=False)
    email = confirm_token(token) # decodes email from token
    # look up email here and save registration info to same user object as email
    if form.validate_on_submit():
```

However first things first and I need to capture the token. Why doesn't the link work to pass the token to the register method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A route of `"/register/<token>"` would require your link to be in the form of `"http://127.0.0.1:5000/register/ImNsdWV...`", where the token is a path element, not a query parameter.

If you want to use a query parameter so the url you've given as example works, you need to use a route of `"/register/"` and then [access](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#flask.Request.args) the token as `request.args['token']` instead of it being passed as argument to the function.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'm checking out the duplicate link as well